# Losing database data after shutting down from `run-rs`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running `mongodb` using `run-rs` instead of `mongod` command since i am using `Transactions` and it requires you to have set of replicas.

Everything is fine except when shutting down the `run-rs` command, the inserted users is gone, and you start from all over again.

Comment: You can find something about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-rs): "Run-rs clears the database every time it starts by default. To override this behavior, use the --keep (-k) flag."

Comment: Thank you, you could write the answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

run-rs clears the database every time it starts by default. To override this behavior, use the **--keep (-k)** flag.

```
run-rs --keep
```